# Pipe pdf to http response with PDFKIT and Strapi (Koa)

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, strapi, pdfkit

I just want to return a pdf in response to a GET Request at my Strapi endpoint.
Strapi uses Koa, and the Strapi controller atm look as follows:

```
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
module.exports = {
   async printOne(ctx) {
      const doc = new PDFDocument();
      ctx.set("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
      // HTTP response
      doc.pipe(ctx.res); 
      // add stuff to PDF 
      doc.text("Hello world!");
      doc.info["Title"] = "Test Document";
      doc.info["Author"] = "Devon Govett";
      // finalize the PDF and end the stream
      doc.end();
   },
};
```

I think the problem is  the doc.end() is closing the stream before the document is built.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work using `pdfmake` and a buffer. Should be similar with `pdfkit`.

```js
const PDFDocument = require('pdfmake');
module.exports = {
  async printOne(ctx) {
    const printer = new PDFDocument()

    const docDefinition = {
      content: [
        'First paragraph',
        'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer.'
      ]
    };

    const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);

    let buffers = [];
    pdfDoc.on('data', buffers.push.bind(buffers));
    pdfDoc.on('end', () => {
      let pdfData = Buffer.concat(buffers);
      ctx.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
      ctx.set('Content-disposition', `attachment;filename=docname.pdf`)
      ctx.body = pdfData
    });

    pdfDoc.end();
  }
};
```